# gulp rev rev-replace crashing

Tags: javascript, gulp

This is a simplified example but I can't get it to work. I am trying to build these steps into my workflow...

1. Look for a file names _head.html (which is an included file snippet that I assemble later)
2. Go get the minified CSS file
3. Rev the CSS
4. Hold onto the new filename somewhere
5. Go write that hashed filename into the HTML file you grabbed in Step 1

heres the relevant code that keeps crashing hard

console output screenshot: http://cl.ly/X8Es

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    rev        = require('gulp-rev');
    revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
    replace    = require('gulp-replace');
    filter     = require('gulp-filter');
    useref     = require('gulp-useref');


gulp.task("revtest", function() {

var cssFilter = filter('css/*.min.css');

return gulp.src("snippets/_head.html")  
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(useref.restore())
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(revReplace())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue. Looking at the sources this should work:

```
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
rev        = require('gulp-rev');
revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
replace    = require('gulp-replace');
filter     = require('gulp-filter');
useref     = require('gulp-useref');

gulp.task("revtest", function() {

    var cssFilter = filter('css/*.min.css');
    var assets = useref.assets();

    return gulp.src("snippets/_head.html")  
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(revReplace())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Comment: I'm going to try this today. Thanks